# How import a group of existing txt files in isolatedStorageDevice in windows phone 7

Tags: file, windows-phone-7, save, isolatedstorage

I have 17 files in .txt, I want import all this files to isolatedStorageDevice.

How can i do this???

remember: i dont wanna write a file i want put a existing file there.

the files are in the folder in Project ,example: (/Files/user.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Manually

Use any existing Windows Phone Isolated Storage explorer tool

Programmatically

You'll have to write a files copy. Assume there is a CordovaSourceDictionary.xml as part of your project which specifies what files must be moved to IsolatedStorage

```
<CordovaSourceDictionary>
    <FilePath Value="www\img\logo.png"/>
    <FilePath Value="www\js\index.js"/>
    <FilePath Value="www\cordova-2.1.0.js"/>
    <FilePath Value="www\css\index.css"/>
    <FilePath Value="www\index.html"/>
</CordovaSourceDictionary>
```

Then you can copy your files using code below

```
StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("CordovaSourceDictionary.xml", UriKind.Relative));

if (streamInfo != null)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(streamInfo.Stream);
    //This will Read Keys Collection for the xml file

    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());

    var files = from results in document.Descendants("FilePath")
                select new
                {
                    path = (string)results.Attribute("Value")
                };
    StreamResourceInfo fileResourceStreamInfo;

    using (IsolatedStorageFile appStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            fileResourceStreamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(file.path, UriKind.Relative));

            if (fileResourceStreamInfo != null)
            {
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fileResourceStreamInfo.Stream))
                {
                    byte[] data = br.ReadBytes((int)fileResourceStreamInfo.Stream.Length);

                    string strBaseDir = AppRoot + file.path.Substring(0, file.path.LastIndexOf(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar));

                    if (!appStorage.DirectoryExists(strBaseDir))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("INFO: Creating Directory :: " + strBaseDir);
                        appStorage.CreateDirectory(strBaseDir);
                    }

                    // This will truncate/overwrite an existing file, or
                    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream outFile = appStorage.OpenFile(AppRoot + file.path, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("INFO: Writing data for " + AppRoot + file.path + " and length = " + data.Length);
                        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(outFile))
                        {
                            writer.Write(data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: Failed to write file :: " + file.path + " did you forget to add it to the project?");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see I named dictionary file as SourceDictionary.xml but it must be CordovaSourceDictionary.xml. You can find a fully working example at https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-wp7/tree/master/example